# If a microwave oven disk rotates to warm up food, why doesn't it go up/down/sideways?

Tags: thermodynamics, waves, microwaves

This has been in my mind for a while... Well, actually everytime I heat any food with a greater amount of liquid in it:

- a microwave oven warms up food by [inducing polar molecules in the food to rotate and produce thermal energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating);
- [it heat foods quickly and efficiently because excitation is fairly uniform in the outer 25–38 mm (1–1.5 inches) of a homogenous (high water content) food item](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven). So, if there's an "heterogeneous, dense object" with liquid right in the center of it (beyond the 25-38mm margin they mentioned), that part won't be heated properly;
- however, the *not so new* ovens were added a disk at the bottom, so the food container can rotate while heating, I suppose for warming up the food uniformly, since the wave is [guided in some pattern to the target](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating#Microwave_heating);
- therefore, wouldn't the heating be more efficient if the container could be moved up, down or even sideways?

Comment: Total guess, might/would be more efficient, but costly to implement, consumer wouldn't pay.

Answer (score 11):

I think this question is more about the engineering (and economics) of manufacturing microwave ovens.

The standing wave pattern can create hot and cool spots in larger food items that are not moving inside the oven.  The rotating plate is sufficient to move the food around so that most of the food is not stuck in a node that creates large temperature differences.  Food directly along the rotation axis moves very little, but it's only a small fraction.  In addition, this region is more likely to be on the interior where the direct heating effects are reduced and temperatures may have more of a chance to equalize after heating.

Moving the entire assembly in one direction would accomplish almost the same (admittedly it would eliminate the static axis) , but would require a more complex mechanism.  Also any translation would reduce the usable volume inside the oven.  A plate that shoved a reheating chicken onto one side of the oven might not be appreciated.

So it becomes a trade-off between more expensive ovens and the chance that small portions of the food on the rotation axis might not be as uniform as other areas.  It seems that most users perceive the microwave oven as a non-precision device and are not willing to pay significantly more for small improvements in cooking ability.

Comment: +1 for the explanation and the _reheated chicken_. It's actually a similar example that I was thinking of, would you eat uncooked/cold meat because the area in the rotation axis was not heated? Several times I pick up the dish, mix everything and put it back again... And for not getting stuck to the walls, the simplest mechanism I am imagining would use springs so we could control the height/length of the container. You could adjust them manually in a cheap oven :)

Comment: @Armfoot:  See if you can patent that idea.  It might appeal to the high-end user.

Comment: @Armfoot, the thing is I don't expect this one fixture would fix the problem entirely, just one (I think minor) part of the problem.  You still have the fact that microwave energy doesn't deposit deeply into the food.  Only the outer portions absorb significant energy.  So you have a more expensive oven, and you still have cold spots in the middle making you stir the food.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Yeah, but some people actually like that part, they think they are cooking their dinner when they need to get involved in some part of the process, like simple stirring,seriously.

Comment: @Armfoot I don't know anything about the workings of microwave ovens, but would moving the microwave-generating element be less complex than moving the food around?

Comment: I was thinking... why not use a Reuleaux triangle, or in the case of a rectangular case, something like you see in a wankel engine? http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Rotation_of_Reuleaux_triangle.gif

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Significantly more complex, for two reasons: the source must be connected by a microwave pipe which doesn't leak waves (they're rather dangerous). This is problematic with a flexible joint. Secondly, the microwave source operates at a high voltage, which requires wires with decent isolation (not really flexible). It would be far easier to alter the standing wave pattern by moving passive reflectors inside the oven.